# The name of parents in my passport do not match the names in their passport. What is the process for visitor visa to travel to Sweden (Schengen)?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, schengen-visas, standard-visitor-visas, sweden

I am from India and currently working and staying in Sweden with a permanent residence permit.
Due to clerical mistakes and mistakes in translating the names from local language to English, the names of my parents in their passport do not match the names of the parents in my passport.

For reference:
Mother's name is - Sushma Devi (in her passport) and Sushmadevi Rana (in my passport)

Father's name is - Rabendra Singh (in his passport) and Ravindra Singh Rana (in my passport)

I want to invite my parents to visit me in Sweden (Schengen/Europe) and also sponsor the trip. What is the process for handling the mismatch in the names?
Has anyone faced similar challenge?
Would a non Judicial document from local attorney about these different names help?

Do I need to specify the 2 names in the invitation letter and the visa application?
Any help on this matter is highly appreciated.

Comment: Is Rana which follows both their names in your passport in fact part of their names?

Comment: Yes, Rana is the family name for us. It is part of my name in the passport as well as theirs in my passport.

Comment: From the many similar questions on this site, this appears to be a fairly common discrepancy in Indian passports, so I suppose that the consular officers will be familiar with it.  Do you actually need to prove that they are your parents?  Do you have a birth certificate, and, if so, how are the names shown there?

Comment: I think it will be easier to correct your passport in embassy rather than Changing details in your parent's passport.